# use Number as Monoid

Tags: haskell, monads

I need to use a number (a Rational ) as the log type of a Writer Monad. Unfortunately , number are not Monoid. Is there a module (or something) instantiating Numbers as Monoid, or should I do it myself ?

***(I just want to know if it exists already somewhere to not reinvent the wheel, I don't need help to do it myself if needed)***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are different possible ways of viewing numbers as a monoid (addition or products), so you have to use a wrapper to select one. See the [docs for Data.Monoid](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Monoid.html) - either `Sum` or `Product`. Obviously if you want some other operation you should write your own.